# What type of roof intake vent is this

Tags: ventilation, roofing

In the attached picture, there seems to be an intake vent on the bottom row of cedar shingles, though maybe I'm mistaken about that, as it has a pretty high profile for an under-shingle intake vent.  Can anyone identify what it is, or its manufacturer?

[image]

Comment: There are a number of manufacturers who make vents in that style. Such as 
  [1]: http://www.airvent.com/index.php/products/intake-vents/the-edge-vent
  [2]: http://www.gaf.com/roofing/residential/products/roof_vents/cobra_intakepro
  [3]: http://www.dciproducts.com/html/smartvent.htm
There are more I can't think of off-hand.

That could be a strange, improper install of one of them or something else entirely. Are you able to get a closer picture?

Comment: It seems much higher profile than they are. I was sent the picture, but I'll ask the person who sent it to me if they can get a closer view. The picture was taken from the road when driving by.